# sending email through external network not working codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, sendmail

I have a problem when sending email using codeigniter and when i'm printing

```
$this->email->print_debugger();
```

it prints:

> "Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol:
>   mail"

but the user can't receive any email after it successfully sends.

here is my code when sending email:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $this->load->helper('string');
    $password= random_string('alnum', 8);

    $data = array ('password' => md5($password),
                           'tag' => 0
            );
    $this->db->where('emp_id', $user['employee_id']);
    $this->db->update('credentials', $data);
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('noreply@company.com', 'company');
    //$this->email->reply_to('noreply@company.com');
    $this->email->to($user['company_email']);   
    $this->email->subject('Password reset');
    $this->email->message('You have requested a code. Here is your code: '. $password);  
    $check = $this->email->send();
```

and here is my code when in my config file:

```
$ci = get_instance();
$ci->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = "sendmail";
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://mail.company.com";
//$config['smtp_port'] = "465";
$config['smtp_port'] = "25";
//$config['smtp_user'] = "person@company.com"; 
//$config['smtp_pass'] = "";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";

$ci->email->initialize($config);
```

when we are in the internal network, i can send email successfully. but when i'm at home trying to send email. the code still works but the user can't receive email. thanks in advance guys !

Comment: do you use the same computer for testing at home? sometimes the mail service is not correctly configured and won't send any email. Also check for closed ports. You can try connecting directly using telnet to check if the connection is possible

Comment: yes im using the same computer when sending email. what is telnet? sorry

Comment: $config['smtp_user'] = "";// Use your real email Id, 
$config['smtp_pass'] = ""; // use same password which you using

Comment: Smtp port 25 might be blocked by your ISP. Try to change it to 587, or use ssl smtp port 465.

Comment: I think this should help you out.... http://www.phpecosystem.com/2014/01/codeigniter-email-library-explored.html

Comment: @AmitHorakeri do you know what is the difference between smtp and mail when sending ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$config['protocol'] = "http";
```

or

```
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
```